# how insert new row in sql server using sqlcommandbuilder object

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net

There is one table called Student in Sql where 4 columns are defined. First column is ID which auto incremented by identity. When I try to insert data in sql then i get the following error :
"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'" on object of SqlCommandBuilder

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);

        string sqlQuery = "insert into Student values where = " + TextStudentID.Text;

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, con);

        SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

        DataSet ds = (DataSet)ViewState["dataset"];

        SqlCommand cmd = builder.GetInsertCommand();
        cmd.Parameters["@StudentName"].Value = TextStudentName.Text;
        cmd.Parameters["@Gender"].Value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
        cmd.Parameters["@Studentmarks"].Value = TextStudentName.Text;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        da.Fill(ds);
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read the [documentation on INSERT statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) and you will see that there is no use of `WHERE` like you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your insert syntax is incorrect. Assuming your ID is the primary key (identity), your insert statement should be like:

```
string sqlQuery = "insert into Student (StudentName, Gender, Studentmarks) values (@StudentName, @Gender, @Studentmarks)";
```

The ID will automatically be inserted and auto-incremented with the other values you are passing.

You should clean up your code a bit and put your SqlConnection in using block so its properly disposed.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
   // your code
}
```

https://www.dotnetperls.com/sqldataadapter

And if you are going to add parameters to your command that way, you need to use  [AddWithValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx), but be aware of the possibility of the wrong implicit type conversion.

Example:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentName", TextStudentName.Text);
```